# Noise sensitivity of Boolean functions

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, learning

Is there any Boolean function from $\{-1,1\}^n$ to $\{-1,1\}$ such that whose noise sensitivity is greater than delta, where Delta is the probability of each bit is flipped in n-tupple.

Comment: Define noise sensitivity, please?.. I want to help, but I don't understand the question without definitions =) quick googling leads to ear problem descriptions, so I tried, but I can't find something standard that fits your description.

Comment: I don't at all understand your definition of Delta.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Ryan O'Donnell](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/)'s work, especially his PhD thesis on the noise sensitivity of Boolean functions:

- [Computational applications of noise sensitivity](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/papers/thesis.pdf) (2003) [pdf]

You may also want to take a look at his blog on Boolean functions:

- [Analysis of Boolean Functions](http://analysisofbooleanfunctions.org/)